# set ip in supertest request

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

with supertest, I can make a resquest to test my node.js application

```
var request = require('supertest');
var api = require('../server').app;

  ...

  it('json response', function(done){

    request(api)
      .get('/api')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res){
        done();
      });
  });
```

how I can set a specific ip to make the test request ?

```
  it('ip access denied', function(done){

    request(api)
      .get('/api')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      // set specific ip
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.body.message.should.eql('Access denied');
        done();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are checking for an ip address with `req.ip` via express (although other frameworks will probably behave the same), 
set `X-Forwarded-For` header in your test with the required ip address:

```
.set('X-Forwarded-For', '192.168.2.1')
```

You might need to enable the [trust proxy](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table) option in your server:

```
app.enable('trust proxy')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the headers that typically contain the IP Address, `Remote-Addr` and `X-Http-Forwarded-For`.  Your app is probably checking one or both of those headers to determine the IP Address.

```
.set('Accept', 'application/json')
.set('Remote-Addr', '192.168.2.1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the ip property using `jest.spyon`

```
import { request } from "express";
// import statementts

const CLIENT_IP = '1.2.3.4';

// make a request
it('ip access denied', function(done) {
  jest.spyOn(request, 'ip', 'get').mockReturnValue(CLIENT_IP);

  request(api)
    .get('/api')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      res.body.message.should.eql('Access denied');
      done();
    });
});
```