# Change testing library IP in some requests?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, supertest

So, I have a express API that checks a list of blocked IPs, if the request IP matches one IP on the IPs blocked list, I want to sent a message to the end-user.

Now I'm implementing tests, I have been using supertest to make calls to my API endpoints

Let's say I want to make two calls the endpoint "/user":

1. one call with IP 127.0.0.1 (default)
2. one call with IP 127.0.1.1 (API should block this IP)

I found some old [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553441/set-ip-in-supertest-request) issues, did everything as shown in the answers, but none answers changed the supertest IP, therefore my API didn't return a message saying the IP was blocked

So, is there a way to automatically test IP bans?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the answers on the question you linked don’t meet your requirements, or more specifically how “*they don’t seem to work anymore*”? Nothing in the Express documentation indicates to me that they shouldn’t function as described any longer.

Comment: I edited the question, so, I implemented the answers, one at a time, and them both together, but it didn't work, when logging the request IP in the express API, the IP was unchanged

Comment: You may want to look into firewall solutions rather than hack into the network stack from express.